# Visual Studio Code: Custom Shortcut to edit source code numbers and divide by two

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't think there is a way to do this but, thought I would ask anyway...
Lets says I have hundreds of numbers in a python script that all need to be divided by 2. Is there any way to create a keyboard shortcut so I can highlight a number, press the shortcut, and it will automatically be replaced with the halved amount? For example, the source code below I would need the first line to convert from `0:4` to `0:2` and the second line to convert from `4:16` to `2:8`. I would do it manually but there are hundreds of numbers to convert right now. Visual Studio code is my IDE that I am using.

```
test1 = word[0:4]
test2 = word[4:16]
test3 = word[16:32]
test4 = word[32:1024]
test5 = word[1024:1086]
test6 = word[1086:1900]
test7 = word[1900:2000]
test8 = word[2000:3000]
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this using python, shell scripts, whatnot -- why on earth is a VSCode extension is your tool of choice?

Comment: I am editing source code, not a txt file. My IDE is visual studio code and I need to be able to replace much of the python source code offsets with their halved results. Does this help answer your question?

Comment: I see. DeepSpace's answer is a good one, but remember that source code is also a file of text and can be processed as such.

Comment: Just to add more information, the reason I want to avoid your approach is that there are many values in the script I do not want to be halved. I am now realizing that the code example I gave is not a good example of why I wanted a keyboard shortcut. Basically I was looking for a simple way to let me pick and chose what values I want changed in code just to make my life a little bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the numbers with the actual value of the expression during the replace with the extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen) v0.8.0

You first select all the text parts matching the same regex as DeepSpace uses, then use the same regex to extract the capture groups per selection and use them as numeric values in a different regex that generates text and that can perform calculations.

It can be handy to put the used regular expressions as comment text in the file. You can copy parts of the file and paste it in the InputBoxes of the extension.

```
# orig regex: word\[(\d+):(\d+)\]
# generate regex: word\[{{=N[1]/2}}:{{=N[2]/2}}\]
```

1. Paste the first regex `word\[(\d+):(\d+)\]` in the Find dialog and tick the regex button (`.*`). If the regex is still selected when you open the Find dialog it will escape a lot of characters, just paste the correct version
2. Click in the document so the focus is no longer in the Find dialog
3. Select all strings matching the Find regex: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
4. Start the command: `Generate text based on Regular Expression (regex)` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
5. Paste the first regex, still in the clipboard, in the `Match Original Text Regular Expression` input box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Select and copy-paste the generate regex to the next input box `Generator Regular Expression`
7. The replace result is shown in the editor, you can accept with <kbd>Enter</kbd> or reject with <kbd>Esc</kbd>

The result with the test file will be:

```
test1 = word[0:2]
test2 = word[2:8]
test3 = word[8:16]
test4 = word[16:512]
test5 = word[512:543]
test6 = word[543:950]
test7 = word[950:1000]
test8 = word[1000:1500]
```

If you need to do this regularly you can define a keyboard shortcut that feeds the regular expressions used into the input boxes and it lets you modify them if needed.

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+f10",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "regexTextGen.generateText",
    "args": {
      "originalTextRegex" : "word\\[(\\d+):(\\d+)\\]",
      "generatorRegex" : "word\\[{{=N[1]/2}}:{{=N[2]/2}}\\]",
      "useInputBox" : true
    }
  }
```

Steps 4 .. 7 are now done with the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using VS code as IDE and are looking to edit source code (and not arbitrary text file), probably the best you can do from within VS code is use find-replace with regex (make sure you select "use regular expression", <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> by default):

search `word\[(\d+):(\d+)\]` and replace with `word[$1/2:$2/2]`, which will result with

```
test1 = word[0/2:4/2]
test2 = word[4/2:16/2]
test3 = word[16/2:32/2]
test4 = word[32/2:1024/2]
test5 = word[1024/2:1086/2]
test6 = word[1086/2:1900/2]
test7 = word[1900/2:2000/2]
test8 = word[2000/2:3000/2]
```

That will evaluate at run time to the output you require.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I need. Thank you. Yes VS Code is my IDE and I am trying to edit source code. I Should have explicitly said that in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure this is absolutely necessary, but you should probably do 0//2:4//2 so that you always get integer division.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find: `word\[(\d+):(\d+)\]`  Replace: `word[$1/2:$2/2]` from @DeepSpace
2. Find: `\d+/\d+`  find all `num/num2`  [no replace]
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select all your `num/num2`'s separately
4. Run `Emmet: Evaluate Math Expression` from the Command Palette (or bind it to a keybinding)

Emmet can do this kind of math.